# find out how many times does that inputed sign appear in the document

Tags: python, text, count

In this program, I want print a document; count the lines and the number of a specific character you ask for in the **input** part. I want to find out **how many times** does that **inputed sign** appear in the document. 
But the program returns the same number as for **num_lines** while the number is not the same. Why is that so? How to make it work and what are some other ways of getting same results? Thanks in advance!

````
file = open('notes.txt', 'r')
for i in file:
        print (i)

num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('notes.txt'))
print('The number of lines in the document is:', num_lines)

signs=input('Input the sign you want to count:')
num_sign = sum(1 for signs in open('notes.txt'))
print('The number of signs in the document is:', num_sign) ```
````

Comment: `file.read().count(sign)`? Might be bad if the file is too big. In that case you can do `sum(line.count(sign) for line in file)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do this:

```py
signs = input('Input the sign you want to count:')

file = open('notes.txt', 'r')
f = file.read()

print('lines:', len(f.split('\n')))
print('signs:', f.count(signs))
```

Comment: thank you @Joan Lara Ganau! this program works perfectly! Could you please explain what does  len(f.split('\n')) do? How did u come up with it and what is /n ??

Comment: @MiriamKaščáková '\n' is the end of line character. It splits the file into a list where each line is a list item.

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
for signs in open('notes.txt')
```

You override your previously declared variable `signs`.

You can replace it with:

```
signs = input('Input the sign you want to count:')
num_sign = 0
for line in open('notes.txt'):
    num_sign += line.count(signs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much my python friend!!  :)

Comment: Just as a side note, you are right with your observation, but it is not the root cause of the problem. The expression `sum(1 for <something> in open('notes.txt'))` will always give the number of lines regardless of what `something` is...